# How to get dropDownList selected value before submit in Yii2?

Tags: yii2

I have a dropDownList in my form like this :

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'object_typeID')->dropDownList(
                ArrayHelper::map(ObjectTypes::find()->all(),'object_typeID','title'),
                [
                    'prompt' => 'Choose Object type',
                ]
            ) ?>
```

and I want to load other form elements based on selected dropDownList value before submit the form so I should have selected value immediately when user select it. How to get dropDownList selected value before submit?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `$model->object_typeID` to the any value of the dropdown values. Here is an example:

```
$model = Model::findOne(3);
echo $model->object_typeID;
// let's say it prints 3
$dropdown = [1 => 'Ejaz', 2 => 'Nizar', 3 => 'Saleem'];
$form->field($model, 'object_typeID')->dropDownList(
            $dropdown,
            [
                'prompt' => 'Choose Object type',
            ]
        )

 // the above code will select Saleem by default.
```

Comment: My dropDownList populated with another db table! I need an Ajax that load other form elements based on user selected value of dropDownList!

Answer (score 0):

do you mean like this? select value from dropDownList and assign value to another fields?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hZ-6huMYxBc&index=24&list=PLRd0zhQj3CBmusDbBzFgg3H20VxLx2mkF

Comment: I don't want assign value to another fields! Actually I need to print some other form elements based on user selected value probably using Ajax

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jquery for this.

```
Step 1: Add an id(say 'listID') to your current field 
Step 2: Add a class(say 'customClassName hide') to next field
Step 3: Find out the value of the selected item from the list using jquery and add/remove class as below :

$('#listID').change(function () {
    var formValue = $(this).val();
    var RequiredValue = '0'; // field to be shown on this value
    if(formValue == RequiredValue){
        newClass = 'show customClassName';
    }else{
        newClass = 'hide customClassName';
    }       
    $('.customClassName').removeClass().addClass(newClass);
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I have so many form elements from another dp table that should be conditionally (based on user select) printed in the form and I can't use show/hide class!! Any other solution?

Comment: My main issue is step 3 : Find out the value of the selected value
:D